# Acumatica make an existing field as NOT mandatory

Tags: customization, acumatica

I am working on Stock Items screen and I want to make all the mandatory fields as NOT mandatory.

For example: the field Base Unit has following DAC

```
[PXDefault(typeof(Search<INItemClass.baseUnit, Where<INItemClass.itemClassID, Equal<Current<InventoryItem.itemClassID>>>>))]
[INUnit(DisplayName = "Base Unit", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
```

I know that we need to remove the [PXDefault] attribute, but what should we replace inplace of that? How will we write the DAC without [PXDefault]?

Comment: seems like a bad idea for Base Unit as its a non nullable field and requires a value. Why would you want a stock item without a base unit? I would think the required fields are required for a reason and needed in other areas of the system. You could be opening a painful user experience doing such changes. Just a thought.

Comment: I am trying to import a spreadsheet...the spreadsheet doesn't have all field values...since these fields are mandatory I am not able to import the spreadsheet and save the changes, I thought I will make the fields mandatory again after importing few spreadsheets.

Comment: when you import and select the item class it should default the value for the item class (for base unit)? the problem is you will at least need to fill in an empty string as the value does not allow nulls (assuming you removed the PXDefault attribute from that field). I still think this is a bad idea. You should provide default/actual values for these missing fields.